# Dictionary<string,List<service>> not allowed in staruml

Tags: c#, staruml

I am using whitestaruml 5.4
with class diagram, i can't seem to be able to type this attribute

```
ServiceCategory: Dictionary<string,List<service>>
```

But `Dictionary<string,List<service>>` is a valid type for C#, how to get over this?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are getting a lexical error on '<' as currently the input analyzer in WhiteStarUML does not accept embedded delimiters ( <[( style ) in the entity names to better handle matching opening/closing at lexer level. In the future this may get more sophisticated but currently the best way to skip parsing is to select the attribute in Model Explorer and fill the "Type" field in Property Inspector. As no parsing happens there it will be accepted. Just make sure not to modify the attribute in the Model View on the Diagram again.

Answer (score 0):

It's June 2022 - still not fixed. Very disappointing.

When directly entering attributes, I just put a placeholder type (e.g., 'foo'). After which, you can go click on the attribute on the right pane and go down to the Editors / type field and replace it with what you want.

I use a lot of map<string,string> and have to do this often. If you try to directly edit a method and its arguments later, it will block you again and you'll have to repeat the procedure - but it can be done to make your diagrams correct. It's just a PITA.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31921377)